# FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hive' '-' 'e'

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have different tables in Hive. I want to save each table in tab-separated file. How can I do it?

If I run this command, I get an error:

```
hive -e 'select * from myTable' > /home/mydata_tsv/myTable.tsv;
```

Error message:

```
NoViableAltException(26@[])
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:740)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hive' '-' 'e'
```

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: I executed this command, not any other command. The only way that works for me is `INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/mydata_tsv' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' SELECT * FROM myTable;`, but it does not create a single TSV or CSV file. Instead it creates multiple hadoopish files.

Comment: You need to execute this from your shell and not from inside the Hive CLI. I think you are executing it from inside the hive shell and that's why insert overwrite works but this doesn't/

Comment: @philantrovert: Ok, thank you. This was the reason. Could you please post the answer?